# VS 2005 Install Problem

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer, registry

All

I have a VS 2005 install set, which when executed seems to run OK however right at the end of the process it responds with the error message:

The source '' is not registered on machine '.' or you do not have write access to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog registry key.

At which point it backs out of the install.  The code in the install pack has had some alteration to it, but nothing that I would expect this sort of behaviour for.

Can anyone assist?  Has anyone out there come across this situation before?

Kind Regards

Paul J.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the installation cannot create a a logsource in the Windows Eventlog. Does the installing user have Administrator permissions? If you are running Vista or Windows 7 you could try to run the installation with administrative permissions (right-click, run as administrator)

Comment: Yes the user (that is me) does have administrator rights.  I have installed this software on the machine on numerous other occassions.  Access policy on the machine is however goverened by a central corporate domain, so will check with them to see if policy has changed.